# How to focus on a textbox in a new page opened using fancybox?

Tags: fancybox, focus, set, setfocus

i have 2 pages, page1 and page2.  the page2 will be loaded in a fancybox upon click on a link in page1. i want to set the focus to a specific textbox on page2 after it has been loaded.  may i know how to do that?

many thanks!

Comment: Can you provide some sample code and a description of what have you tried?

Comment: is page2 opened in `iframe` mode?

Comment: sorry for taking too long for my response. till now i haven't found the solution for my problem. here is the code that i used but won't work

$('.fancyboxTopic').fancybox({
   helpers:{overlay: {closeClick:false}},
   'padding': 5,
   'width': '840px',
   'height': '95%',
   'autoScale': false,
   'autoHeight': false,
   'autoSize': false,
   'afterClose': function(){window.location.reload(true);},
   'onComplete': function(){$('#topicTitle').focus();}
})

Answer (score 0):

sorry for taking too long for my response. till now i haven't found the solution for my problem. here is the code that i used but won't work

code in page1

```
$('.fancyboxTopic').fancybox({
   helpers:{overlay: {closeClick:false}},
   'padding': 5,
   'width': '840px',
   'height': '95%',
   'autoScale': false,
   'autoHeight': false,
   'autoSize': false,
   'afterClose': function(){window.location.reload(true);},
   'onComplete': function(){$('#topicTitle').focus();}
})
```

in my link:

```
<a href="page2.asp" class="fancyboxTopic fancybox.iframe">page 2</a>
```